# How can I style a string or substring placed into a Drupal node field?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

In Drupal 6, I have a custom node that consists of just one plaintext field.

I'd like to be able to detect the following string: "@[name]" where [name] is a string with no whitespace. Ideally, it would be nice to wrap this text in a span with an id, so I can then style it as I wish. The main challenge is that the string is not fixed, so could be any arbitrary peice of text.

Is there a module that exists for this type of thing, or can I implement with hooks? I looked at String overrides, but that's only for fixed strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can just create a custom template for that content type.  Then you can wrap the field in any element you like and make the node look however you like as well.  Take a look at the following example of theming custom content types:  [Example: Theming a Specific CCK Content Type](http://drupal.org/node/266817)

Comment: Apologies if I've got the wrong end of the stick here, but I don't want to theme my content type. I just want to detect from the presence of a particular substring when the form is submitted, so I can render that string somehow in a different style.

For instance, if someone were to type "foo" into the text field, then when the node is displayed (by itself or in a view), the word "foo" will have a blue background and blue text.

It's kind of like syntax highlighting, I guess.

Comment: Ok, while theming your content type, you can add the `<span>` or `<div>` around the field and give it an id/class depending on the value of the field.  Then use simple CSS to theme the output. Apologies if I am still missing what you are getting at.

Comment: I don't think so -- what I am trying to say is that, if you have a node, and you put some text in one of the fields, like this:

"I am going to see @Laxman13 today"

I need some way of being able to style "@Laxman13", but with the extra caveat that "@Laxman13" could be "@persepolis" or "@foo". The only constant is that there is an @ symbol followed by a string.

Comment: Ahh I see, thanks for clearing that up! Have you looked at any syntax highlighting modules? You may be able to set your own rules (not sure, haven't checked them out). Another route could be regular expressions used within a preprocess function

Answer (score 1):

Provided that you're using Views to display your field and PHP code is enabled, you should be able to put @[name] within a span or a div by selecting "Rewrite output of this field" and using regular expressions to return the string you need to highlight.

Finding the RegEx shouldn't prove to difficult, it would probably be something along the lines of:

```
Find the character "@" followed by any number of characters
```

Sorry, I don't use RegEx often enough to give you the exact code, but it shouldn't take you long to find out.

Then it's only a question of returning the string and adding some tags.